# python excel csv help. how to do formatting

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a problem. If I explain it in words, I will mess up, so here it is in pictures.

my code:

```
import csv

def mytest():
    s1 = 'post'
    s2 = 'a_num'
    s3 = ['personA','GenderA','personB','GenderB','personC','GenderC','personD','GenderD','personE','GenderE',]
    s4 = ['comment by F','comm_F_gender','comment','ano_num','comment by G','comm_G_gender','comment','ano_num','comment by H','comm_H_gender','comment','ano_num']      
    with open('mytestfb.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                                quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        spamwriter.writerow([s1.encode('utf-8'),s2.encode('utf-8')])
        x = 0
        while(x < len(s3)):
            spamwriter.writerow(['','',s3[x].encode('utf-8'),s3[x+1].encode('utf-8')])
            x += 2
        x = 0
        while(x < len(s4)):
            spamwriter.writerow(['','','','',s4[x].encode('utf-8'),s4[x+1].encode('utf-8'),s4[x+2].encode('utf-8'),s4[x+3].encode('utf-8')])
            x += 4
```

This is what this code is doing:

[image]

this is what I need the code to do:

[image]

Comment: Your code, as posted, does neither.

Comment: @MartijnPieters whoops! wrong code lol. it has now been edited to make it match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can't be the whole code can it?  So if I understand every four items in s4 and two items in s3 represent a row.

```
def mytest():
    s1 = 'thing1'
    s2 = 'a_number'
    s3 = ['personA','GenderA','personB','GenderB','personC','GenderC','personD','GenderD','personE','GenderE',]
    s4 = ['comment by F','comm_F_gender','comment','ano_num','comment by G','comm_G_gender','comment','ano_num','comment by H','comm_H_gender','comment','ano_num']      
    with open('mytestfb.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        exportlist=[s1,s2]
        for count in range(len(s3)/2):
            exportlist+=s3[count*2-1:count*2]
            try:
                exportlist+=s4[count*4-1+count*4]
            except IndexError:
                pass
        spamwriter.writerow(exportlist.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: No, it isnt the whole code but it is the part I am having trouble with. In a nutshell, I am extracting information from online and putting it into excel. I extract it into this format.

Comment: Sorry: that was responding to your original post.  Basically, when you use 'writerow' it creates a new row, which I don't believe you can add to without closing the file and reading it again.  Or doing what I suggested.  Hope it was helpful

Comment: Sorry also realized that you will get an index error with that, and so I fixed it to duplicate what I think you are going for.  Sorry if I am offbase